# How can I change the letter tokenizer (elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

How can I change the letter tokenizer (elasticsearch) so that the numbers treated as letters.
For example, the text: 
"car bmw727" letter tokenizer break into 
"car", "bmw" 
and I want to:
"car", "bmw727"

Is it possible to change an existing letter tokenizer, or define new the pattern tokenizer?

Answer (score 0):

For your use case pattern tokenizer with the default settings would be suffice enough:

```
"my_index_analyzer" : {
  "tokenizer" : "pattern"
}
```